# A for loop that is looping through a large list in ANT is causing a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, ant, out-of-memory

I have to admit I am not familiar with ANT and did not write most of the code below from scratch. What I am trying to do is loop through a list of filenames which is saved in a file seperated by commas. The code executes fine until it gets to somewhere around the 1400th filename. For each filename, it is calling a java procedure that executes a query to retrieve a pdf file and save it locally. I believed it may be running out of memory because the connection that is opened in the Java procedure isn't closed but I confirmed it is. So I think its due to the list of filenames being too large. Any ideas on how to deal with large lists?

The error I get after around the 1400th iteration is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:  unable to create new native thread

Thanks.

```
<for list="${filenames}" delimiter="," param="filename">
    <sequential>
            <propertyregex override="yes" property="trimmedname" input="@{filename}" regexp="[\s]*([^\s].*[^\s])[\s]*" replace="\1"/>
            <if>
                <and>
                <length string="${trimmedname}" trim="true" when="greater" length="0" />
                <not><equals arg1="${trimmedname}" arg2="$${filenames}" /></not>
                </and>
            <then>
                <java classname="LOBExtract" failonerror="true" fork="true" maxmemory="512m">
                    <arg value="DBSERVER=${server_name}"/>
                    <arg value="DBPORT=${oracle_port}"/>
                    <arg value="DBSID=${oracle_sid}"/>
                    <arg value="DBUSER=${dbuser}"/>
                    <arg value="DBPASSWORD=${dbpassword}"/>
                    <arg value="TABLE=BLOB_DATA"/>
                    <arg value="LOBFIELD=BLOB_DATA"/>
                    <arg value="WHERE=blob_id=${trimmedname}"/>
                    <arg value="FILENAME=${output_dir}/aircraft/esig/files/${trimmedname}.pdf"/>
                    <classpath>
                        <pathelement location="."/>
                        <pathelement path="${basedir}"/>
                        <pathelement path="${basedir}/resource/ojdbc14.jar"/>
                    </classpath>
                </java>
            </then>
            </if>
        </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Does removing `fork="true"` change anything?

Comment: Could you give more memory , say maxmemory="1200m". Is Ant giving OOM or the LOBExtract ?

Comment: Ant is giving the OOM. It crashes on the call to LOBExtract saying it cant create a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Using some sort of hash, is more efficient for large sets of data compared to using a List or arrayList.